# pass django template file content to javascript

Tags: javascript, django, django-templates

I want to pass a template file content to my javascript file for later use to create DOM elements there.
What I have tried is to pass it to js as a variable with an include tag like this:

```html
<script>const list_item = {% include 'myapp/list_item.html' %}</script>
```

But this end up getting:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'

Is there a way I can pass template file content to js file?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking just at your sample (not making any recommendations about other possible ways to achieve the desired result), it should be:

```html
<script>const list_item = "{% include 'myapp/list_item.html' %}";</script>
```

The content of the template file should be included as a string, otherwise it will keep throwing a syntax error.

Comment: Thanks! It solved the problem only that I had to use ` instead of " to avoid conflict with templates double quotes.